# How do I read the content of a txt file in Azure Storage Container?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage

I have an container in my Azure storage and i just want to read the content of the txt files and the date the file was created. I do not wish to download the file itself. i found some answers to that but the once i found where out of date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Downloading the file and reading the content is essentially the same thing, just wording. No need to save the file physically to disk. You can do a .DownloadText() on your CloudBlockBlob object, which returns a string.

```
var cloudBlockBlob = GetCloudBlockBlob();
cloudBlockBlob.FetchAttributes();
var created = cloudBlockBlob.Properties.Created;
var content = cloudBlockBlob.DownloadText();
```

You obviously need to implement your own GetCloudBlockBlob() method.